# unable to read querystring in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my url which contains 4 querystrings(desc,url,img,title).

> http://localhost:4385/Default?desc=Home%20Page&url=http://localhost:4385/&img=http://localhost:4385/images/ribbon-img.png&title=

I read querystrings like below,

```
 string title = Request.QueryString["desc"];
 string pageurl = Request.QueryString["url"];
 string alttext = Request.QueryString["title"];
 string imageurl = Request.QueryString["img"];
```

The output i get is:

```
title=Home Page&url=http://localhost:4385/&img=http://localhost:4385/images/ribbon-img.png&title="
```

it takes entire url to first querstring, this is not my expected output.

I expect values to all querystring variables

can anyone please help me

Comment: how are you hitting this Url - ajax call or a direct call to the website? it looks like the value is getting encoded. Also make sure that there is no double quotes.

Comment: directly using response.redirect(url);

Comment: you should encode query string values similar to targetURL = "~/?Xresult=" +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(res); and then call response.redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL format is incorrect i feel, because the slash `/` character will be sent as `%2F` in the query string but that was not done in your URL format.

Update:

```
Respose.Redirect("http://localhost:4385/Default?desc=Home%20Page&url="+Uri.EscapeDataString("http://localhost:4385/")+"&img="+Uri.EscapeDataString("http://localhost:4385/images/ribbon-img.png")+"&title=");
```

Comment: you mean to encode query string in the url and then do response.redirect

Comment: @sandeep Use Uri.EscapeDataString("your string which may contain the special characters")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not creating the QueryString with proper encoding. .NET framework has [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) to simplify this problem of encoding. Try this code

```
//are you sure your URL doesn't have an ".aspx" extension?
var url = " http://localhost:4385/Default.aspx?";
var queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
queryString["desc"] = "Home Page";
queryString["url"] = "http://localhost:4385/";
queryString["image"] = "http://localhost:4385/images/ribbon-img.png";
queryString["title"] = "";
Response.Redirect(url + queryString.ToString());
```

Now the QueryString will look like this.

> var urlWithQueryString = " http://localhost:4385/Default.aspx?desc=Home+Page&url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a4385%2f&image=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a4385%2fimages%2fribbon-img.png&title="

Now parsing can be done using the method you tried

```
string title = Request.QueryString["desc"];
string pageurl = Request.QueryString["url"];
string alttext = Request.QueryString["title"];
string imageurl = Request.QueryString["image"]; //you have wrongly typed "img" here
```